# Unwanted padding on the bottom of div

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with the header div of this website I'm making.  There is padding or something appearing underneath my horizontal menu bar even though my padding is set to 0. I know that similar posts have been made about the but I have read quite a few and none of the answers seemed to do the trick for me. I have changed the background of the header div to yellow to make it more visible. There is also a pixel or two on either side of the menu bar which are unwanted. I'll put my css and html code below. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0JhB.jpg)

```
<div class="big header">
<img src="Images/headerphoto.jpg" alt="header_photo">
<div class="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.asp">About Us</a></li>
        <ul class="logo">
        <li><a class="logo" href="http://www.linkedin.com"><img alt="in" src="Images/linkedinlogo.png"></a></li>
        <li><a class="logo" href="http://www.facebook.com"><img alt="fb" src="Images/facebooklogo.png"></a></li>
        <li><a class="logo" href="http://www.twitter.com"><img alt="tw" src="Images/twitterlogo.png"></a></li>
        <li><a class="logo" href="http://www.rss.com"><img alt="rs" src="Images/rsslogo.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

And here is the relevant CSS. (The 'Big' class is what I'm using for all the major elements on the page.)

```
body {
   background-image:url("Images/background.png");
   background:tile;
}

.header img {
   width: 100%; 
}

.header {
   background-color: yellow;
   height: auto;    
   padding-top: 30px;
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
   margin-top: 10px;
}


.big {
   width: 80%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #C5C5C5;
}
```

Here is the css for my navbar.

```
.button {
background-color: #3EB5F5;
border: none;
color: white;
transition: all 0.5s;
cursor: pointer;
}

.button span {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
content: '»';
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
top: 0;
right: -20px;
transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
opacity: 1;
right: 0;
}

.navbar {
width: 100%;    
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px; 
}

.navbar ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #828080;
height: 38px;
}

.navbar li {
float: left;
}

.navbar li a[href$=".asp"]{
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 16px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
height: 100%;
}

.navbar li a[href^="http"] {
padding-top: 6px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}

.logo img {
width: 25px;
}

.logo {
float:right;
list-style-type:none;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.active {
background-color: #106AAA   
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is badly formed. You have closed the `li` before the submenu. Start there. A demo would be useful too.

Comment: Have you tried setting margin-top of .navbar to 0? Also try setting .header * (.header and all children) to box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: @Paulie_D when I put the submenu into a <li></li> it causes the submenu to go to the far left right after the initial menu, but does not remove the weird padding.  I'm not sure what you meant by a demo though. Also I have tried adding a css reset to my css file.

Comment: @Ber I tried setting margin-top to 0 and .header * to border box.  Some things move a bit but always the padding.

Comment: Are you still experiencing the padding issue? [On jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shambolaz/7w4ym735/), the aforementioned rules resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I have added an example to show http://codepen.io/simondavies/pen/jWjoBy

It working please check out the css, html etc

I have guestimated some stuff... Hope it will be a help

```
    <div class="big header">
      <div class="header-img"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=1000%C3%97150&w=1000&h=150" alt="header_photo"></div>
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.asp">About Us</a></li>
          <li><!--<ul class="logo"></ul>--></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .header {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .header-img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 30px 0 15px 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .header-img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .big {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #C5C5C5;
  }

  .button {
    background-color: #3EB5F5;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .button span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .button span:after {
    content: '»';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .button:hover span {
    padding-right: 25px;
  }

  .button:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
  }

  .navbar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #828080;
    height: 38px;
  }

  .navbar li {
    float: left;
  }

  .navbar li a[href$=".asp"] {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .navbar li a[href^="http"] {
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .navbar li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
  }

  .logo img {
    width: 25px;
  }

  .logo {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .active {
    background-color: #106AAA
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.asp">About Us</a></li>
        <ul class="logo">
```

The only descendants of either `<ul>` or `<ol>` should be `<li>`. It is *possible* that this could be the issue.

I corrected the markup in two ways,  [without reproducing your issue](http://codepen.io/paceaux/pen/jWjobM):

- By wrapping `<ul class="logo">` inside of an `<li>` (essentially assuming it was a sublist in your list
- By closing your first `<ul>`, and then letting the second list sit adjacent to it

But I also could not reproduce your issue  [by leaving the markup alone](http://codepen.io/paceaux/pen/OMeeYE)

So, the issue may be:

1. You need to use a [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) to remove default margins and paddings that the browser is providing
2. There is another ruleset that is adding padding to your `.header`

   - That other ruleset may have a higher specificity
   - That other ruleset may have an `!important` declaration